# Python - valuecounts() method - display all results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a complete novice when it comes to Python so this might be badly explained.

I have a pandas dataframe with 2485 entries for years from 1960-2020. I want to know how many entries there are for each year, which I can easily get with the `.value_counts()` method. My issue is that when I print this, the output only shows me the top 5 and bottom 5 entries, rather than the number for every year. Is there a way to display all the value counts for all the years in the DataFrame?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `pd.set_options` and set `display.max_rows` to `None`:

```py
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
```

Now you can display all rows of your dataframe.

- [Options and settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)
- [pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html)

Comment: alternative to consider, display top N e.g. 50: df['year'].value_counts()[0:49]

Answer (score 5):

If suppose the name of dataframe is 'df' then use

```
counts = df.year.value_counts()
counts.to_csv('name.csv',index=false)
```

As our terminal can't display entire columns they just display the top and bottom by collapsing the remaining values so try saving in a csv and see the records